# input output exception handling

Tags: java, input, exception, output

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Throwing {
    static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int x = getInt();
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static int getInt() throws IOException {
        try {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type a number: ");
            int value = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You typed the integer ");
        }
        catch (IOException expection) {
            System.out.println("Not a integer");
        } 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The program is: if you have integer, it will say it is integer otherwise throw IOException that      it is not integer.
I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
at Throwing.getInt(Throwing.java:13)
at Throwing.main(Throwing.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `scanner.nextInt()` doesn't throw `IOException` when the int is not valid, it throws `InputMismatchException`, so you need to catch `InputMismatchException` to detect invalid int input.

Or you could use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) to detect whether valid int was entered instead of using try-catch.

Comment: I changed that still it gives me error for int x = getInt(); part whenever I typed non integer.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the try block never throws an IOException. Remove the try-catch block wrapping your code. It will return InputMismatchException instead.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether it is valid integer and throws IOException if it is not, do this

```
if(console .hasNextInt()){
   int value  = console .nextInt();
   System.out.println("You typed an integer:" + value);
}else{
   throw new IOException("It is not an integer");
}
```

Comment: I got that part for my other example. For here, I have to use IOException.

Comment: just throw IOException if it is not an integer